# SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 <= col2?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select rows from a table where the value of `column_x` is less than `column_y`.  This is what I've got:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM table_name 
           WHERE timestamp <= '$timestamp' 
             AND hit_counter <= max_hits";
```

Does anyone have any idea if this will work, and if not what I could do to get this kind of functionality :).

Comment: Should work just fine. Have you tried this yet? You can also try running the query from MySQL to see if it will work.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I haven't even built the table. I was just looking for clarification beforehand, plus since I couldn't find another SO post on the topic, I thought it might come in hand for others who are looking to do the same thing :).

Comment: The syntax seems to be correct. Have you tested this?

Comment: Here's a tutorial for php + mysql: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/  I recommend you read it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly. Here's a test case in SQL Server but it's the same in MySQL:

```
create table #test
(
a int,
b int
)

insert into #test
values (1,2),(2,2),(5,4),(5,2)

select a,b from #test

a   b
1   2
2   2
5   4
5   2

select a,b from #test where a<=b

   a    b
   1    2
   2    2
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks proper but I would try to remove the timestamp <= '$timestamp' portion first and re-execute.  That's the only part I can see issues coming up.   $timestamp could perhaps be the wrong format and/or the '' will render the value incorrectly a string.

Comment: the single quotes around the $var are recommended when injecting  $vars in queries. It never hurts to quote a number as a string in MySQL, it **will** seriously bite to **not** quote a string. Always use quotes!

Comment: I'm probably basing my answer on a past problem experience with the quotes... although if I try to recall it correctly, it may have been an issue of not having quotes.  Oops